# Qt.DecorationRole crash when trying to add icon into Qtableview

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

I developed a df with multiple cols and want to add icon 'green_tick.jpg' & 'red_cross.jpg' into the last 2 col according to the boolean value

last 4 cols of the df

[image]

Here is the class I built for displaying the df into the Qtableview and insert the icon.

```
Class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
            return str(value)

        if role == Qt.DecorationRole:
            value = self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
            if isinstance(value, bool):
                if value :
                    return QtGui.QPixmap("green_tick.jpg")

                return QtGui.QPixmap("red_cross.jpg")


    def rowCount(self, index):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        # section is the index of the column/row.
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                return str(self._data.columns[section])

            if orientation == Qt.Vertical:
                return str(self._data.index[section])
```

However, it keeps crashing and shows up error msg as below:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\andyt\Desktop\Programming\Project\Project_4\main.py", line 265, in
in data
    value = self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
  File "C:\Users\andyt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
 line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\andyt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\basse.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1618, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTablle.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1626, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTablle.get_item
KeyError: 6
```

Does anyone know why and how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I turn True and False into a string and then apply the following code as a solution because I believe the line with isinstance causing the problem.

```
class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data, criticaltime):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self.criticaltime = criticaltime
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
            return str(value)

        if role == Qt.DecorationRole:
            value = self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
            if value == 'In Stock':
                return QtGui.QIcon(QtGui.QPixmap("C:\\Users\\andyt\\Desktop\\Programming\\Project\\Project_4\\green_tick.jpg"))
            elif value == 'Out of Stock':
                if datetime.datetime.strptime(str(self.criticaltime), "%Y-%m-%d") > datetime.datetime.strptime(str(self._data['EAD'].iloc[index.row()]), "%Y-%m-%d"):
                    return QtGui.QIcon(QtGui.QPixmap("C:\\Users\\andyt\\Desktop\\Programming\\Project\\Project_4\\warning.png"))
                return QtGui.QIcon(QtGui.QPixmap("C:\\Users\\andyt\\Desktop\\Programming\\Project\\Project_4\\red_cross.jpg"))

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        # section is the index of the column/row.
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                return str(self._data.columns[section])

            if orientation == Qt.Vertical:
                return str(self._data.index[section])
```